# Why this list isn't showing me, prime numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, foreach

I'm practicing with Lists, I'm making a list of numbers and then adding only the prime numbers of this list to another one and everything is okay until I get to the part of the code where I want to confirm that the number is prime, I don't if there's something missing, here's my code:

```
List = []
Primes = []
x = 0
for i in range(0,6):
    List.append(int(input()))

flag = False
for e in List:
    print(e)
    for div in range(2,e):
        if e%div == 0:
            flag = True
    if flag == False:
        Primes.append(e)
        
        
print(List)
print(Primes)
```

And I get this Output:

```
[1, 42, 5, 8, 7, 56, 2, 34]
[]
```

Comment: You must reset the `flag` inside the first `for` loop. Also note that 1 is not prime (your code will think that it is).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and recomendation, appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work:

```py
List = []
Primes = []
x = 0
for i in range(0,6):
    List.append(int(input()))


for e in List:
    flag = False
    #print(e)
    if e == 1:
      print("1 is neither prime nor composite")
    else:
      for div in range(2,e):
         if e%div == 0:
            flag = True
      if flag == False:
         Primes.append(e)
        
        
print(List)
print(Primes)
```

a problem was that it wasn't setting `flag` to `False` after each test

also note that most people consider 1 not prime nor composite, so I added that there as well

Answer (score 0):

this will get you your primes of a list:

```
from math import sqrt
from itertools import count, islice

l = range(6)

def is_prime(n):
    return n > 1 and all(n % i for i in islice(count(2), int(sqrt(n)-1)))

primes = [i for i in l if is_prime(i)]
```